# React Leaflet change maker when hover over outside element

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using React and Leaflet-React. I have a map and a stack of cards similar to yelp. I would like to change the map marker when someone hover overs the card that represents that site.  I have mapmarkers that change depending on the status. Each key on the map maker has a unique key that matches the card key.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }  from "react";
import FetchSites from "../../data/FetchSites";
import L from "leaflet";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const customOfflineMarker =  L.icon({
  iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/offline.png",
  iconSize: [50, 50],
  iconAnchor: [25, 5],
});
const customGreenMarker =  L.icon({
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/pin_static_green.png",
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    iconAnchor: [25, 5],
  });

  const customYellowMarker =  L.icon({
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/pin_static_yellow.png",
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    iconAnchor: [25, 5],
  });

  const customRedMarker =  L.icon({
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/pin_static_red.png",
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    iconAnchor: [25, 5],
  });

  const customPurpleMarker =  L.icon({
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/pin_static_purple.png",
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    iconAnchor: [25, 5],
  });
const customSelectedMarker =  L.icon({
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/pin_selected.png",
    iconSize: [50, 50],
    iconAnchor: [25, 5],
  });
function mapMaker(props) {
    return L.icon({
        iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/img/mapmakers/static/offline.png",
        iconSize: [50, 50],
        iconAnchor: [25, 5],
      });
}



function Dashboard() {
  
  const [response, loading, hasError] = FetchSites("api/data");
  return (
    <div className="listing-map-wrapper">
      <div className="listing-main-wrapper">
        {loading ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : hasError ? (
          <div>Error occured.</div>
        ) : (
          <div>test</div>
        )}

        {response.map((item) => (
          <>
            {item.siteTypeId} - {item.siteType.en}
            {item.sites.map((site) => (
              <div className="col-lg-4">
                <div className="card-item d-flex">
                  <div className="site-level"></div>
                  <div className="card-image">
                    {site.siteImage ? (
                      <img
                        className="card__img"
                        src={`data:image/png;base64,${site.siteImage}`}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-conent-wrap">
                    <h4 className="card-title">{site.siteName}</h4>
                    <h4 className="card-title">
                      {site.lat} - {site.long}
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="listing-map">
        <MapContainer
          className="markercluster-map map"
          center={[39.73899, -104.99102]}
          zoom={12}
        >
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          {response.map((item, i) => (
            <>
              {item.sites.map((site) => (
                <>
                
                  {site.parameters.map((parameter) => (
                      <>
                    <Marker
                      key={site.siteId}
                      position={[site.lat, site.long]}
                      icon={(() => {
                        switch (parameter.parameterStatusItemId) {
                          case 1:   return customGreenMarker;
                          case 2:   return customYellowMarker;
                          case 3:   return customRedMarker;
                          case 4:   return customPurpleMarker;
                          case 5:   return customPurpleMarker;
                          default:  return customOfflineMarker;
                        }
                      })()}
                    >
                      <Popup>
                        <div className="mapboxgl-popup mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top">
                          <div className="mapboxgl-popup-tip" />
                          <img
                            src={`data:image/png;base64,${site.siteImage}`}
                            alt={site.siteName}
                          />
                          <div className="acr-listing-popup-body">
                            <h5>
                              <Link to="#" title={site.siteName}>
                                {site.siteName}
                              </Link>
                            </h5>
                            <p>
                              <i className="fas fa-map-signs" />
                              {site.siteDescription}
                            </p>
                            <div className="location-popup-meta">
                              <span>
                                <i className="fas fa-bed" />
                                {site.siteDescription2}
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    </>
                  ))}
                </>
              ))}
            </>
          ))}
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
'''
```

Comment: if you provide a demo or a github repo I could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are going to want to maintain a state variable that determines whether or not a card is being hovered over, and keep the id of that card in it:

```js
function Dashboard() {
  const [highlightedCard, setHighlightedCard] = useState()
  // your other code
}
```

Your card element will need to have mouse events attached to determine when the user mouses over, or when they mouse out:

```js
// in the return statement ...

{response.map((item) => (
  <>
    {item.siteTypeId} - {item.siteType.en}
    {item.sites.map((site) => (
      <div 
        className="col-lg-4" // assuming this is your card container element...
        onMouseEnter={() => setHighlightedCard(site.siteId)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHighlightedCard(null)}
      >

  // the rest of your code continues...
```

So now, on mouse in, the card's id is set in state, and set back to null on mouse out.  Now in your markers array, you can use that state variable:

```js
{site.parameters.map((parameter) => (
  <>
    <Marker
      key={site.siteId}
      position={[site.lat, site.long]}
      icon={(() => { 
        if (site.siteId === highlightedCard){ // use state variable here
          return specialHighlightedMarker     // or whatever
        } else {                              // customize this as needed
          switch (parameter.parameterStatusItemId) {
            case 1:   return customGreenMarker;
            case 2:   return customYellowMarker;
            case 3:   return customRedMarker;
            case 4:   return customPurpleMarker;
            case 5:   return customPurpleMarker;
            default:  return customOfflineMarker;
          }
        }
      })()}
    >

  // code continues
```

I didn't test this, but as @kboul said, if you provide a working demo (codesandbox, codepen, etc), we can better help you implement it.  Just looking at code on the page, this is how I would approach this.